# Detecting unnecessary Haskell mutually recursive modules

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there some tool or some GHC flag for detecting unnecessary mutually recursive modules?

Comment: GHC refuses to compile mutually recursive modules unless you go through a *lot* of steps. Seems like that's sufficient detection..

Comment: I am not asking how to detect mutually recursive modules, but the **unnecessary** ones (written by someone else, long time ago).

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by unnecessary. Do you mean 'factorable into not recursive modules'? Because that's always the case! Do you mean 'imports that aren't used'? Because -fwarn-unused-imports will do that. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Let's suppose in a large project after using `-fwarn-unused-imports` I removed `import {-# SOURCE #-} Foo` from a module. How I know if I can erase the `Foo.hs-boot` file?

Comment: I usually try a textual search for something like `import Foo`. You can do a better job by using regexes. You can also inspect the modules that GHC compiles if you recompile the whole project, but it may take time.